# Making a trackable human body - Oculus Rift

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I'm very new to this. During my research for my PhD thesis I found a way to solve a problem and for that I need to move my lab testing in the virtual environment. Anyway, I have an Oculus Rift and an OPTOTRAK system that allows me to motion capture a full body for VR (in theory). What my question is, can someone point me in the right direction, of what materials do I need to check out to start working on a project. I have a background in programming, so it's just that I need a nudge in the right direction (or if someone knows a similar project)

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301721674_Insert_Your_Own_Body_in_the_Oculus_Rift_to_Improve_Proprioception - I want to make something like this :)

Tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Nice *challenge* too.. how accurate and how real time is the image of your body in the Oculus Rift world ? my two - or three - cents

- A selfie-based approach would be the most comfortable to the user.. there's an external camera somewhere and the software transforms your image to reflect the correct perspective, as you *would* see your body, through the oculus, at any moment. This is *not* trivial and quite expensive vision software. To let it work 360 degrees there should be more than 1 camera, watching all individual oculus users in a room !
- An indirect approach could be easier.. model your body, only show dynamics. There's WII style electronics in bracelets and on/in special user clothing, involving multiple tilt and acceleration sensors. They form a cluster of "body state" sensor information, to be accessed by the modeller in the software. No camera is needed, and the software is not that complicated when you'd use a skeleton model.
- Combine. Use the camera for the rendering texture and drive the skeleton model via dynamics drive  by the clothing sensors. Maybe deep learning could be applied, in conjunction with a large number of tilt sensors in the clothing, a variety of body movement patterns are to be trained and connected to the rendering in the oculus. This would need the same hardware as the previous solution, but the software could be easier and your body looks properly textured and it moves less "mechanistic". There will be some research needed to find the correct deep learning strategy..